# How to train a model for XOR using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

Is there a magic sequence of parameters to allow the model to infer correctly from the data it hasn't seen before?

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

clf = MLPClassifier(
                activation='logistic',
                max_iter=100,
                hidden_layer_sizes=(2,),
                solver='lbfgs')
X = [[ 0,  0],  # 2 samples, 3 features
     [0, 1],
#      [1, 0],
    [1, 1]]
y = [0, 
     1,
#      1,
     0]  # classes of each sample
clf.fit(X, y)

assert clf.predict([[0, 1]]) == [1]
assert clf.predict([[1, 0]]) == [1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `y` be `[0, 1, 0]`?

Comment: Yup. Sorry. Playing with the code many times. But the question still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to use [kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html)?
Kernel is a way of a model to to extract the desirable features from data.

Generally used kernels may not satisfy your requirement.
I believe they try to find **'cut' hyperplane** between **one hyperplane** which contains `[0, 0]` and `[1, 1]` and **another hyperplane** which contains `[0, 1]`.

In 2-dimensional space, for example, **one hyperplane** is `y = x` and **another hyperplane** is `y = x + 1`. Then **'cut' hyperplane** could be `y = x + 1/2`.

So I suggest the following kernel.

```
def kernel(X1, X2):
    X1 = np.array([[(x[0] - x[1]) ** 2] for x in X1])
    X2 = np.array([[(x[0] - x[1]) ** 2] for x in X2])
    return np.dot(X1, X2.T)
```

What this kernel does is this. It squares the different between two scalars; (x - y)<sup>2</sup>.
With this way of feature extraction, data will be featurized like the following:

- `[0, 0]` → `[0]`
- `[0, 1]` → `[1]`
- `[1, 1]` → `[0]`

And also for the unseen datum:

- `[1, 0]` → `[1]`

So the following trained classifier will `predict`s as you desire; (`[1, 0]` → `[1]`).

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel, max_iter=100)
```

Model selection is very important in machine learning. A model which does not know that `[0, 0]` and `[1, 1]` are in the same group and
`[0, 1]` and `[1, 0]` are in the other same group
may not make the prediction you expect.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It works! Although from what I can tell it will only work for this specific scenario. But yeah, thanks! I learned a few things. I just started learning machine learning!

Comment: @haalcala Nice bro. Check [Non-Linear SVM and Kernel Function](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/non-linear-svm-and-kernel-function-7174bbecc2d3) as well.

Comment: For different scenarios, you should make your assumption over data and you can design your custom kernels.